# Enlazar dos páginas php

Tags: php

Cómo se enlaza dos páginas php. Ejemplo la página de conexión a la base de datos con otra quizá de portafolio . Y en el tema de enlazarlo también con archivos css y bootstrap à mi n me funciona. Uso VScode tengo todo lo necesario para ejecutar php en el navegador (Chrome) pero sale sin estilo alguno

Comment: Por favor crea un [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

si quieres hacer la inclusión de código, puedes usar lo siguiente:

Usar `include` -> [La sentencia include incluye y evalúa el archivo especificado.](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.include.php)

```
<?php
    include("conexion.php");
    //
    //Podemos hacer consultas hacia la BBDD, etc.
    //
?>
```

Usar `require` -> [require es idéntico a include excepto que en caso de fallo producirá un error fatal](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.require.php)

```
<?php
    require("conexion.php");
    // Mismo caso que antes
?>
```

---

De este modo, puedes incluir más páginas, secciones, etc. Ejemplo:

```
<?php
include("header");
?>
<body>
    <!-- Codigo html aca -->
</body>
```

---

Ahora, para enlazar las páginas de CSS a nuestro codigo...

Dentro de las etiquetas `<head>` ponemos un `link` del siguiente modo:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
</head>
```